# How to create Udacity-like lecturer hand with Final Cut Pro X?

Tags: finalcut

I am currently working on creating an online course. I would like to reproduce the "hand" kinda like [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSqR5xMk2QI). I understand that Udacity films the graphics table from above and also captures the screen with a tool like Camtasia or whatever screen recorder one likes.

So, I am working with Final Cut Pro X, it would be nice to be able to achieve this with this tool. I have basically two videos, one of the camera filming the hand and one from the screencapture. What I wanna do is, get rid of everything but the hand in the camera video and put it in the background of the screen capture video.

Any ideas?

Kind regards,

Nils

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Keyer plug-in in Final Cut Pro X, if you filmed the hand in front of a green or blue screen. If you instead filmed it in front of white or black, you should use the Luma Keyer. Then you can simply layer the hand over the screen-capture video in the timeline.